# Trying to determine if a 2D polygon is concave or convex by implementing a given suggestion

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, glm-math

I am trying to implement **trinitrotoluene's** suggestion for checking if a polygon is concave or convex found in [here](https://community.khronos.org/t/algorithm-to-detect-the-type-of-a-polygon/55974/3).

What I tried so far is implementing this suggestion using **glm**, but for some reason or another, I am getting a false result.

Here are my vertices which give a concave polygon:

```
glm::vec2 v1(0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec2 v2(1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec2 v3(0.5f, 0.5f);
glm::vec2 v4(1.0f, 1.0f);
glm::vec2 v5(0.0f, 1.0f);

std::vector<glm::vec2> vertices;
vertices.push_back(v1);
vertices.push_back(v2);
vertices.push_back(v3);
vertices.push_back(v4);
vertices.push_back(v5);
```

And here is the solution implemented:

```
bool IsConvex(const std::vector<glm::vec2> &vertices)
{
    glm::mat2 mat(vertices.at(0).x, vertices.at(1).x, vertices.at(0).y, vertices.at(1).y);
    float rez = glm::determinant(mat);

    for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++) 
    {
         glm::mat2 mat(vertices.at(i).x, vertices.at(i).y, vertices.at((i+1)%vertices.size()).x, vertices.at((i + 1) % vertices.size()).y);
         float det = glm::determinant(mat);

         rez = rez * det;
    }

    if (rez < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The given polygon is concave, but **trinitrotoluene's** suggestion implementation gives me a false result, getting as output a `true` value for `IsConvex()` which states that the polygon is convex when it should be a `false` value.

Comment: Your first matrix is initialized in `xxyy` order, while those in the loop are in `xyxy` order. Is that normal? Additionally, you're using the coordinates of the vertices when IIUC you should use the vectors between those vertices instead.

Comment: First, those in the loop were wrong, I corrected it (it should be `xxyy` since the matrix is build on columns first, and following **trinitrotoluene's** pattern), thank you for that. Second, you are correct, it should be the edge vectors, something signalled in an answer in this [link](https://community.khronos.org/t/algorithm-to-detect-the-type-of-a-polygon/55974/10) as well. I corrected my mistakes and everything works accordingly. Cheers!